# How to multiply lists of lists together in Erlang?

Tags: matrix, erlang, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiple two matrices together, and I have code that makes the matrices and displays them using a list of lists. But I cannot figure out how to multiply the two matrices I have together.

Here is my code so far:

```
-module(main).
-export([main/0]).
-export([matrix/2, random/2]).

main() ->
    MatrixA = random(3, 100),
    MatrixB = random(3, 100),

    main:matrix(MatrixA, MatrixB).

matrix(MatrixA, MatrixB) ->

    Print = fun(X) -> io:format("~w, ", [X]) end,

    io:fwrite("Matrix A: "),
    lists:foreach(Print, MatrixA),
    io:fwrite("\n\nMatrix B: "),
    lists:foreach(Print, MatrixB),
    io:fwrite("\n\nMatrix C: "),
    io:fwrite("\n").

random(Size, MaxValue) ->
    random(1, 1, Size, MaxValue, [], []).

-define(VALUE(X, Y), value(X, Y, MaxValue)).

value(_, _, MaxValue) ->
    rand:uniform(MaxValue).

random(Size, Size, Size, MaxValue, Row, Acc) ->
    [[?VALUE(Size, Size) | Row] | Acc];

random(Size, Y, Size, MaxValue, Row, Acc) ->
    random(1, Y+1, Size, MaxValue, [], [[?VALUE(Size, Y) | Row] | Acc]);

random(X, Y, Size, MaxValue, Row, Acc) ->
    random(X+1, Y, Size, MaxValue, [?VALUE(X, Y) | Row], Acc).
```

Also, is there a way to alter this code so that the numbers in the matrix are decimal values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NOTE: StackOverflow isn't really the place to tackle homework-type problems, but matrix multiplication is interesting because its listy nature is pretty central to the way we do almost everything in functional programs, so it can be a sort of showcase of different approaches. I think it will be pretty much impossible to submit my code below as homework (especially because it is now [indexed](http://zxq9.com/archives/1387) on my own site, which is indexed by most schools' plagiarism detectors), but I **do** think you stand a chance of growing as a programmer if you meditate on this code, and mess around with and modify it to **make it your own**. And that's good for everyone.*

## Quick Note on Lists

To simply multiply a list against a list a few different approaches can be used. List comprehensions are pretty common:

```
multiply(Scalar, Row) ->
    [Scalar * Value || Value <- Row].
```

Also for multiplying permutations of lists against lists:

```
multiply(ListA, ListB) ->
    [A * B || A <- ListA, B <- ListB].
```

This gets you part of the way, but isn't quite what you want. You need to make that go deeper, and there are also actually [quite a few rules to matrix multiplication](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult2.htm), and if we don't want to write a *completely* mathematically flawed module we should probably include at least some of the input checks necessary to validate the input or *at least crash* on obviously bad input.

## A Full-blown Example

I initially set out to explain why list operations work the way they do, but I wound up writing a whole naive matrix multiplication module to illustrate the point, so... meh, whatever.

I used list operations where I thought they were really obvious (and colsure of an in-scope value was convenient) and explicit recursion elsewhere (because there is a bit of state floating around in some of these operations, especially rotation).

**READ THEM CAREFULLY**

Pay particular attention to the way the `random/2` and `random/3` functions work, and compare them with your code. The version below is *much* simpler to reason about, and that is a *good thing*. As much as possible try to not make future readers of your code maintain a bunch of ongoing state in their brain when they read a single line, like having list operations or generators within another list operation -- unless it is a *very simple* transform that is going on and the statements are more expressive than if they were split apart.

Also, [make use of labels](http://zxq9.com/archives/1337) that make your code self-documenting whenever possible.

As a final note on style, notice that the style here has typespecs (for [Dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) -- here's [a primer](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer) -- *learn this*), edoc annotations and is written in a way that complies with the style used for [zuuid](https://github.com/zxq9/zuuid), which is [a project written specifically to serve as a platform for discovering sound style and an example of the result](https://zxq9.com/archives/1293).

```
%%% @doc
%%% A naive matrix generation, rotation and multiplication module.
%%% It doesn't concern itself with much checking, so input dimensions must be known
%%% prior to calling any of these functions lest you receive some weird results back,
%%% as most of these functions do not crash on input that go against the rules of
%%% matrix multiplication.
%%%
%%% All functions crash on obviously bad values.
%%% @end 

-module(naive_matrix).
-export([random/2, random/3, rotate/1, multiply/2]).

-type matrix() :: [[number()]].


-spec random(Size, MaxValue) -> Matrix
    when Size     :: pos_integer(),
         MaxValue :: pos_integer(),
         Matrix   :: matrix().
%% @doc
%% Generate a square matrix of dimensions {Size, Size} populated with random
%% integer values inclusive of 1..MaxValue.

random(Size, MaxValue) when Size > 0, MaxValue > 0 ->
    random(Size, Size, MaxValue).


-spec random(X, Y, MaxValue) -> Matrix
    when X        :: pos_integer(),
         Y        :: pos_integer(),
         MaxValue :: pos_integer(),
         Matrix   :: matrix().
%% @doc
%% Generate a matrix of dimensions {X, Y} populated with random integer values
%% inclusive 1..MaxValue.

random(X, Y, MaxValue) when X > 0, Y > 0, MaxValue > 0 ->
    Columns = lists:duplicate(X, []),
    Populate = fun(Col) -> row(Y, MaxValue, Col) end,
    lists:map(Populate, Columns).


-spec row(Size, MaxValue, Acc) -> NewAcc
    when Size     :: non_neg_integer(),
         MaxValue :: pos_integer(),
         Acc      :: [pos_integer()],
         NewAcc   :: [pos_integer()].
%% @private
%% Generate a single row of random integers.

row(0, _, Acc) ->
    Acc;
row(Size, MaxValue, Acc) ->
    row(Size - 1, MaxValue, [rand:uniform(MaxValue) | Acc]).


-spec rotate(matrix()) -> matrix().
%% @doc
%% Takes a matrix of {X, Y} size and rotates it left, returning a matrix of {Y, X} size.

rotate(Matrix) ->
    rotate(Matrix, [], [], []).


-spec rotate(Matrix, Rem, Current, Acc) -> Rotated
    when Matrix  :: matrix(),
         Rem     :: [[number()]],
         Current :: [number()],
         Acc     :: matrix(),
         Rotated :: matrix().
%% @private
%% Iterates doubly over a matrix, packing the diminished remainder into Rem and
%% packing the current row into Current. This is naive, in that it assumes an
%% even matrix of dimentions {X, Y}, and will return one of dimentions {Y, X}
%% based on the length of the first row, regardless whether the input was actually
%% even.

rotate([[] | _], [], [], Acc) ->
    Acc;
rotate([], Rem, Current, Acc) ->
    NewRem = lists:reverse(Rem),
    NewCurrent = lists:reverse(Current),
    rotate(NewRem, [], [], [NewCurrent | Acc]);
rotate([[V | Vs] | Rows], Rem, Current, Acc) ->
    rotate(Rows, [Vs | Rem], [V | Current], Acc).


-spec multiply(ValueA, ValueB) -> Product
    when ValueA  :: number() | matrix(),
         ValueB  :: number() | matrix(),
         Product :: number() | matrix().
%% @doc
%% Accept any legal combination of scalar and matrix values to be multiplied.
%% The correct operation will be chosen based on input values.

multiply(A, B) when is_number(A), is_number(B) ->
    A * B;
multiply(A, B) when is_number(A), is_list(B) ->
    multiply_scalar(A, B);
multiply(A, B) when is_list(A), is_list(B) ->
    multiply_matrix(A, B).


-spec multiply_scalar(A, B) -> Product
    when A       :: number(),
         B       :: matrix(),
         Product :: matrix().
%% @private
%% Simple scalar multiplication of a matrix.

multiply_scalar(A, B) ->
    multiply_scalar(A, B, []).


-spec multiply_scalar(A, B, Acc) -> Product
    when A       :: number(),
         B       :: matrix(),
         Acc     :: matrix(),
         Product :: matrix().
%% @private
%% Scalar multiplication is implemented here as an explicit recursion over
%% a list of lists, each element of which is subjected to a map operation.

multiply_scalar(A, [B | Bs], Acc) ->
    Row = lists:map(fun(N) -> A * N end, B),
    multiply_scalar(A, Bs, [Row | Acc]);
multiply_scalar(_, [], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).


-spec multiply_matrix(A, B) -> Product
    when A       :: matrix(),
         B       :: matrix(),
         Product :: matrix().
%% @doc
%% Multiply two matrices together according to the matrix multiplication rules.
%% This function does not check that the inputs are actually proper (regular)
%% matrices, but does check that the input row/column lengths are compatible.

multiply_matrix(A = [R | _], B) when length(R) == length(B) ->
    multiply_matrix(A, rotate(B), []).


-spec multiply_matrix(A, B, Acc) -> Product
    when A       :: matrix(),
         B       :: matrix(),
         Acc     :: matrix(),
         Product :: matrix().
%% @private
%% Iterate a row multiplication operation of each row of A over matrix B until
%% A is exhausted.

multiply_matrix([A | As], B, Acc) ->
    Prod = multiply_row(A, B, []),
    multiply_matrix(As, B, [Prod | Acc]);
multiply_matrix([], _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).


-spec multiply_row(Row, B, Acc) -> Product
    when Row     :: [number()],
         B       :: matrix(),
         Acc     :: matrix(),
         Product :: [number()].
%% @private
%% Multiply each row of matrix B by the input Row, returning the list of resulting sums.

multiply_row(Row, [B | Bs], Acc) ->
    ZipProd = lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> X * Y end, Row, B),
    Sum = lists:sum(ZipProd),
    multiply_row(Row, Bs, [Sum | Acc]);
multiply_row(_, [], Acc) ->
    Acc.
```

Note that the above code *does not* make your matrices as float values. There is an Erlang BIF called [float/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#float-1) that takes any number and returns a float -- so it is, of course, possible to make the above code do whatever you want in this regard with a minimum of fuss.